# Checking for backspace

Tags: bash

If I do

```
read -n 1 c
```

and enter a backspace.

How do I test that `$c` contains a backspace?

```
[ "$c" = $'\b' ]
```

doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do is have a program where I can read a line and have it  instantly available even before the line is finished:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ttySettings=`stty --save`
stty -echo
str=
while read -n1 c; do
  if [ -z "$c" ]; then
    break
  fi
  if [ "$c" = $'\b' ]; then
    str="${str%?}"
  else
    str="${str}$c"
  fi
  printf '\r'
  for((i=0;i<COLUMNS;i++)); do
    printf ' '
  done
  printf '\r%s' "$str"
done
echo "$str"
stty "$ttySettings"
```

I basically want to filter a list based on the entered line (to be shown below the entered line) and I want that filtering to be live.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `$'\177'` instead of `\b`:

```
if [ "$c" = $'\177' ]; then
    echo 'Whoa, we got a backspace!'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Your check for backspace seems to work.  However, the script for clearing the line is not working (for me, with bash 4.2.37).  The loop following

```
printf '\r'
```

could be replaced with [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html):

```
tput el1
```

(*before* printing the `\r`).

Comment: It does not for me. `$'\177'` does. Thanks for the `tput el1`, suggestion though.